# Saving every rows of pandas dataframe to txt file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, hdf5

So, I open a dataset from a HDF5 file like below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = pd.read_hdf('sport.hdf5', usecols=['category','title','images','link','date','desc'])
```

It will give me output like below:

```
category                                              title  images  \
0      raket  Kevin/Marcus Langsung Fokus ke Kejuaraan Dunia...     NaN   
1         f1         Vettel Menangi GP Inggris yang Penuh Drama     NaN   
2     others  Semangat 'Semakin di Depan' Warnai Kejuaraan M...     NaN   
5  sepakbola             Roberto Martinez Mengejar Status Elite     NaN   
6  sepakbola  Nyaris Separuh Gol Piala Dunia 2018 Lahir dari...     NaN   

                                                link  \
0  https://sport.detik.com/raket/d-4104834/kevinm...   
1  https://sport.detik.com/f1/d-4104788/vettel-me...   
2  https://sport.detik.com/sport-lain/d-4105193/s...   
5  https://sport.detik.com/sepakbola/berita/d-410...   
6  https://sport.detik.com/sepakbola/berita/d-410...   

                             date  \
0   Senin 09 Juli 2018, 00:31 WIB   
1  Minggu 08 Juli 2018, 22:35 WIB   
2   Senin 09 Juli 2018, 11:15 WIB   
5   Senin 09 Juli 2018, 12:35 WIB   
6   Senin 09 Juli 2018, 12:51 WIB   

                                                desc  
0   - Setelah  , Kevin Sanjaya/Marcus Gideon suda...  
1   - Driver Ferrari   keluar sebagai pemenang Gr...  
2   - Kejuaraan Dunia Motocross Grand Prix (MXGP)...  
5             -   bisa jadi mulai kerap diperbinc...  
6             - Berakhirnya perempatfinal Piala D...
```

---

Now, I need to save every single row that contain **desc** with the title of **title**, I'm using the code belom:

```
np.savetxt(data1['title']+'.txt', data1['desc'], fmt='%s')
```

but, it come out with the result like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 23, in <module>
    np.savetxt(data1['title']+'.txt', data1['desc'], fmt='%s')
  File "/home/adminsvr/tf-py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1187, in savetxt
    if fname.endswith('.gz'):
  File "/home/adminsvr/tf-py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3614, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Any solution or ideas?

Comment: Please post the result from `print(data1.head())`.

Comment: EDITED showing the resulth from data1.head()

Answer (score 0):

After hours of working, here's the idea to solve the problem:

First, make iteration of rows for Data1 dataframe. Don't forget to add attribute iterrows that will return row selection. And don't forget to define index and rows.

To make file for every row, define the directory followed by (row[title]) to make it dynamic.

However, the directory *result/* is not exist yet. User makedirs to make it.

And finally, write (row[desc]) inside the txt file.

Here we go:

```
import os

for idx,row in data1.iterrows():

    filename = "result/"+str(row['title'])+".txt"
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename), exist_ok=True)
    with open(filename, "w+") as f:
        f.write(row['desc'])
    f.close()

    print (idx)
```